# Toggle contentEditable on click

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to make a div contentEditable when it is clicked, and then set contentEditable to false on mouseout, but I've had no success so far. Clicking a link appears to highlight it, but otherwise does nothing at all:

http://jsfiddle.net/GeVpe/19/

```
<div id="content" contentEditable="true" onclick = "this.contentEditable = true;" onmouseout = "this.contentEditable = false;">
    Surprisingly, <a href="http://google.com">clicking this link does nothing at all.</a> How can I fix this problem?
</div>
```

I expected the link to take me to the linked page when it was clicked, but instead, it was highlighted when clicked and did nothing else. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It turns out that the link is not working even when it isn't inside a contentEditable div. I think I've found out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994328/clicking-a-link-has-no-effect-at-all

Comment: Anderson Green is right - it's because jsFiddle uses iFrames. Also a somewhat generic solution using classes is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dirkk0/8CNyw/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jameswyse/b5b9f42bf38e7c09262cb37ea44ce626

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ever use inline html script declaration, thats a bad practice. I think the reason your link doesn't do anything is, that the event listener bubbled/propagated over it and changed its default onclick event, when you set it for your div.

I suggest you do something like this.

```
        window.onload = function() {
            var div = document.getElementById('editable');
            div.onclick = function(e) {
                this.contentEditable = true;
                this.focus();
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#E0E0E0';
                this.style.border = '1px dotted black';
            }

            div.onmouseout = function() {
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
                this.style.border = '';
                this.contentEditable = false;
            }
        }

        // And for HTML

        <div id="content">
            <span id='editable'>Surprisingly,</span>
            <a href="http://google.com">clicking this link does nothing at all.</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: How do you know that inline script declaration is considered a bad practice?

Comment: Did you test this script yet? I tried running it, and still had the same problem as before: http://jsfiddle.net/GeVpe/20/

Comment: It is bad to mix up javascript with HTML, when you can do it in a better way, I guess you can use it for some simple operations but eventually you will find that it is not enough for you. If you google this issue you will find many articles about it.

Yes, I tried the script before posting it. It doesn't work for me in your jsfiddle test neither. I don't know why. Try testing it outside of the jsfiddle. Just put it in a html file and run it in your browser. Works fine for me.

Comment: The question of whether or not to use event handler attributes is completely separate from the problem at hand.

Comment: I tested the solution that was posted here, and it still doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/xSPgC/ You need to set the target of the link to `"blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the target to `blank`:

```
<div id="content" contentEditable="true" onclick = "this.contentEditable = true;" onmouseout = "this.contentEditable = false;">
    Surprisingly, <a href="http://google.com" target = "blank">clicking this link does nothing at all.</a> How can I fix this problem?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can make html element editable true and false using this code.

```
    $( "#mylabel" ).click(function() {
// we get current value of html element
        var value = $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable');
//if its false then it make editable true
    if (value == 'false') {
        $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable','true');
    }
    else {
//if its true then it make editable false
        $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable','false');
    }
    });
```

Comment: It's better to [add more context/explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Comment: Thanks, for your comment I have  added content .