# Clicking a link in an iframe has no effect at all

Tags: javascript, html

In Google Chrome, I've noticed that clicking some links seems to have no effect at all:

```
<a href="http://google.com">clicking this link does nothing at all.</a>
```

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/epileg/1/edit) and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQhbe/).

Is this normal, or does it indicate that there is some kind of bug with the latest version of Google Chrome? I've never had this issue before, and links like these used to work just fine for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at your developer console, you'll see the following:

`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: However, setting `target = "blank"` seems to allow the page to be opened in a new tab.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, of course. Both JSBin and JSFiddle run code in iframes. What you're experiencing is a security measure to prevent a parent page interfering with content or stealing passwords or user information.

Answer (score -3):

This is because of the fact that you can't display external pages in iframes. This is a browser limitation mostly for security reasons

Comment: What can you display in iframes, then? Are they restricted to pages on the same domain?

Comment: You can display external pages in iframes. It just depends on whether that page has set its `X-Frame-Options` to prevent it.

Comment: Yes, this is a browser limitation. If this wasn't in place a hacker, for example, could inject a malicious iframe to an exploit kit or some other kind of external code or html that you don't want on your website.

Comment: My mistake apparently it's not a browser limitation but the website itself puts this limit on you.

Comment: Just to let you know, deleting this answer will increase your reputation, since it has downvotes.