# Custom placeholder with contentEditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/cp1ntk45/

I write a function to replace original html placeholder, then I can style the placeholder text.

it works fine with input and textarea element,
problem if the target is 
contentEditable div, after click once not focus in, not be able to type, need to click second times to focusin ...
How to make only click one time and focus in

```js
var placeholder = function(el) {
  el.on('focusin', function() {
    var val = $(this).text();
    
    var placeholder = $(this).attr('data-placeholder');
    
    if (val == placeholder) {
      if ($(this).attr('data-empty') != 'false') {
        
        $(this).text('');
      }
    }
  });
  el.on('focusout', function() {
    var val = $(this).text();
    var placeholder = $(this).attr('data-placeholder');

    if (val == '') {
      $(this).text(placeholder);

      $(this).attr('data-empty', 'true');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-empty', 'false');
    }
  });
};

placeholder($('.textarea'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="textarea" contentEditable="true" data-placeholder="placeholder">placeholder</div>
```

Comment: The attached fiddle is working fine for me.

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine for me.

Comment: it need to double click to focus in

Comment: Why do you use JS at all. It can all be done using CSS

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ? you mean original html placeholder attribute, it can be style css font color and size with input, textarea?

Comment: @user1575921 well, not the original but using `data-*`. See example below.

Answer (score 16):

You can use **CSS** `:empty` and `:before` on your `contenteditable` element.
Using the `content: attr(data-placeholder);` you can then *stamp* any  text you want.

```css
[contenteditable] {padding:12px; background:#eee; }

[data-placeholder]:empty:before{
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  color: #888;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable data-placeholder="I'm a placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: after focusout not replace placeholder again

Answer (score 0):

solve this by change the attribute `contentEditable` after click and focusout event, like below

```
el.on('click', function() {
  $(this).attr('contentEditable', 'true');
  $(this).focus();
});

el.on('focusout', function() {
  $(this).attr('contentEditable', 'false');
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15993398/5593189