# How do I make a <div> contentEditable on doubleclick using Svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, svelte-3

I'm brand new to **Svelte** (3.0+)...and for my latest project, I'd like to emulate the functionality of many "todo" lists that allow you to edit todo items previously submitted by double-clicking on them ([Here's an example of the functionality I'm looking for](http://svelte-todomvc.surge.sh/)).

I imagine, the first step is figuring out how to make a div `contentEditable` with Svelte with the `on:dblclick` event handler. I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for this task (though I can do it with [vanilla javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993128/toggle-contenteditable-on-click)).

Here's the Svelte code I have so far: ( Here it is on [CodeSandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-doubleclick-to-make-div-content-editable-9pu06) - see page: CEDiv.svelte)

```
<script>
function edit(event) {
    //update db functionality goes here
    //alert("you've 'submitted' your edit")
}

function handleDblClick() {
    //I need help HERE...and probably on the div on:dblclick down below....
}
function handleKeydown() {
    key = event.key;
    keyCode = event.keyCode;
    //submit the div's content to the edit function if enter or tab is pressed.
    keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 9 ? edit(event) : null;
}
</script>
<style>
div.read-mode {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.edit-mode {
    padding:10px;
    background: lightgreen;
    border:3px solid green;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    width:496px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
<div on:dblclick={handleDblClick} class="read-mode" on:keydown={handleKeydown} contentEditable="false">
    I want this Div to be editable one double click.
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to grab the div element associated with the clicked element then add a child input element, when editing is done, grab the value of the input element then remove the input element from the div.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a boolean variable

```
let editable = false;
```

which will be changed inside your handler

```
function handleDblClick(event) {
  editable = true; // or use  editable=!editable  to toggle
}
```

bind your `editable` variable inside the attribute,
and take a look how to dynamically toggle the class `"edit-mode"` using a ternary operator

```
<div 
  on:dblclick={handleDblClick} 
  class={editable ? 'edit-mode': 'read-mode'} 
  on:keydown={handleKeydown}
  contenteditable={editable}>
    I want this Div to be editable on double click.
</div>
```

[Here's a CodeSandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-doubleclick-to-make-div-content-editable-zg0n8)

Comment: This works well...and I think it's more "officially" Svelte...which is what I'm trying to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @Doomd yes, that's the "data binding" way Svelte inherited from predecessors. You're welcome.